# Using FromData vs FromBody attribute on api .net core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2, frombodyattribute

I have a .net core api written which integrates with swagger. Now I'm trying to make swagger page be user friendly but I am not willing to sacrifice security to do so. However, I don't have enough understanding and experience on the said topic and I'm looking for either some reference to get me started or even a straight answer works too.

Currently on my actions I use `[FromForm]` decorator which then requires a `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;` to be passed in order to work. Since the intended caller is an angular application, it can easily accommodate that with a `FormData` object. This has been tested and all works great. Now if I were to use `[FromBody]` decorator then the the expected value should be `Content-Type: application/json` which is more api appropriate as I understand but my swagger then is hard to work with. It wants a formatted json value when testing as oppose to each field offering an input and validating types like dropdowns and such.

What are the implications of me using `[FromBody]` vs `[FromForm]` in terms of security, is one more secure than the other or is one more preferred than the other and why?

Comment: In terms of security, both are the same. however switching from `[FromBody]` to `[FormData]` will have compatibility issues with existing clients. existing clients must support JSON data

Comment: @ArjunVachhani I'm not sure what you mean by existing clients.

Comment: If API is used by clients then they may need to modify code to support JSON data in the request body

Comment: @ArjunVachhani I'm sorry I just don't understand who you are referring to when you say clients?

Comment: Clients = programs consuming your API